# Hook to display element as product on category page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, hooks

I am creating a plugin and I am trying to add an element which will be displayed as a product. In the picture, the element is the red rectangle.

[image]

I have used [this](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/#more-19370) guide but none of the hooks there helped me.
I tried `woocommerce_before_shop_loop`, it adds the element behind the products, spending the whole page (in the DOM tree, it adds it as the parent of the products elements.

Also, `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` insert the element inside the product's element container, before the sale badge.

Which hook can I use to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't the hooks in that guide help? What are you having trouble with? What do you mean by "an element which will be displayed as a product"?

Comment: So you want to insert arbitrary html between two woocommerce products? Which theme are you using?

Comment: Edited the question for more information. @FabrizioMele, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the shop loop to insert something between some products. The file where the loop happens is `wp-plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` ([this one](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/archive-product.php)). Override it using [this guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and do something like this

```php
$counter = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) {
  if($counter == 5){ //if you want your code between the 5th and the 6th product
    echo "<li ".wc_product_class( '', $product ).">";
    echo "My Html!";
    echo "</li>";    
  }
  the_post();

  do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
  wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  $counter++;
}
```

Please note that I took the `<li>` from the default woocommerce `content-product.php` template, you might want to look for the template in your theme, if it is overridden.

As you are trying to override a template through a plugin you need to inject your plugin `woocommerce` (or call it what you want) directory inside the woocommerce template search scope. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43776583/1425266) has a good code example on how to do it.

Comment: If I understand right, the guide describes how to do it while editing the files and by a theme. How can I do it through a plugin?